# How to diff entire SVN check-ins between different branches?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Here's what I need to do a lot on daily basis.
I merge back fixes from the main branch into patch branches.
The assumption is that the merge files should be exactly the same between the branches when that happens. I'm tired of doing manual file diff between the two check-ins.

Does anybody know about any tool that would allow me to provide two SVN numbers from two different branches and list for me all the involved files and whether they are the same or not between the two check-ins?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of files that differ between two branches with the `--summarize` option:

```
svn diff path-to-branch-one path-to-branch-two --summarize
```